# Disable hamburger to arrow animation

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, android-5.0-lollipop, android-support-library

I am trying to implement a two-drawer layout with the android v7 support library. I have a navigation drawer on the left (Gravity.START) side and a notification drawer on the right (Gravity.END) side. The problem is that I need the hamburger in the action bar to stay a hamburger when the notification drawer is pulled out, but stay animated and change to an arrow if the navigation drawer is pulled out. Currently it changes to an arrow when either one is pulled out. I have successfully disabled the animation by overriding `onDrawerSlide(View, float)` and only calling to `super.onDrawerSlide(View, float)` if the View is the navigation drawer and doing nothing if the View is the notification drawer like this:

```
@Override
public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
    // Make sure it was the navigation drawer
    if(drawerView.equals(navigationDrawer)) {
        super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
    }
    else {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

However, once the notification drawer has fully opened, the icon still changes to an arrow. Any idea how to disable this change?

Comment: Try doing the same for `onDrawerOpened` and `onDrawerClosed`

Comment: @EugenPechanec Extremely simple fix and achieved exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much. Post as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: Glad I could help, good luck with your app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Along with handling `onDrawerSlide` you need to handle both `onDrawerOpened` and `onDrawerClosed`:

```
@Override
public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
    // Make sure it was the navigation drawer
    if(drawerView.equals(navigationDrawer)) {
        super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView, slideOffset);
    }
    else {
        // Do nothing
    }
}

@Override
public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
    // Make sure it was the navigation drawer
    if(drawerView.equals(navigationDrawer)) {
        super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView, slideOffset);
    }
    else {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no method in ActionBarDrawerToggle like onDrawerOpened(View drawerView, float slideOffset) . Then how it works

Comment: Just use `onDrawerOpened(View)`, I didn't use the `float slideOffset` argument in the example anyway. Looks like the method was deprecated for the same reason.

Comment: @Aurélien Lepage's answer is the correct answer as Google has made it easy to disable sidle animation in newer versions of support library. ```yourActionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerSlideAnimationEnabled(false);```

Answer (score 2):

Since support v7 version 25.3.0, you can disable the animation

```
yourActionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerSlideAnimationEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The above accepted answer not working for me but the below one does

```
@Override
public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
    super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, 0); // this disables the animation 
}
```