# Disable NavigationDrawer icon's slide animation

Tags: android, android-animation, navigation-drawer, slidingdrawer, drawerlayout

Is there any way to disable sliding animation of the NavigationDrawer's icon? I mean the effect, when you click the icon or open the Drawer with slide gesture. (I still use the ActionBar at the moment)

***Preview***

[image: Preview]

Comment: why are you using the old style navigation drawer and not the new style

Comment: What do you mean by new style?

Comment: see here http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: @marson hamburger icon.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I'm planning to start with the Material design right after finishing my current project

Comment: @marson reason I say that is because the new style goes over the icon so you dont even need to worry about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the `onDrawerSlide` method of `ActionBarDrawerToggle` and set the **slideOffset to 0** if the drawer is right drawer. So this would disable the animation of the navigation drawer image.

```
  @Override
  public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) 
  {
        if(drawerView!=null && drawerView == rightDrawerListView){
              super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, 0);
        }else{
              super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
        }
  }
```

Comment: Works, but i deleted the "drawerView == rightDrawerListView" part of the if-else statement. What do you mean by "rightDrawerListView" ?

Comment: Actually I wrote the code from my project, I'm pulling the Navigation Drawer from right side. `drawerView == rightDrawerListView` is used to disable animation if it is pulled from right side. [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156340/android-is-navigation-drawer-from-right-hand-side-possible) if you want Navigation Drawer at the right side.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27772072/disable-hamburger-to-arrow-animation). Since support v7 version 25.3.0, you can disable the animation, you can disable the animation using one line of code.

`yourActionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerSlideAnimationEnabled(false);`