# Override onDrawerSlide not showing in android studio auto-complete list

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to disable the navigation drawer button animation using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29351461/7283160), but I can't override the `onDrawerSlide` cause it is not showing in the auto-completion list.

[IMAGE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3wAS.png)

As a newbie here and in Android app development, how can I include it? What am I missing here?

**Toolbar.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**MainActivity.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.android.demo.Main">

    <!-- Toolbar -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include android:id="@+id/toolbar" layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.android.demo;

import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Drawer
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_open, R.string.navigation_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Access the `OnDrawerSlide` method , you have to override the method which is implimented in `ActionBarDrawerToggle` class, example is shown below

```
drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
            getToolbar(), R.string.open, R.string.close) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Oh, damn... It was clearly stated in the answer I've linked in my question, I just didn't get it at first... Thanks!

Comment: @HumblePotatoII your wlecome :)