# Xamarin.Forms: how to disable arrow to hamburger transition animation on Android?

Tags: android, animation, xamarin.forms, hamburger-menu

I've created a **basic sample app with Xamarin.Forms**, where I tried to repoduce a UI like Twitter or Instagram with:

- a **MasterDetail** page as main page, where the default "hamburger" icon
  is replaced by a custom icon
- a **"bottom" TabbedPage** as detail of the MasterDetail page
- a control allowing to implement **top Tabs** in the TabbedPage
- **ContentPages** that are hosted in **NavigationPage** for each
  tab of the TabbedPage

So, the the **pages architecture** of my app looks like this:

> |-- MasterDetailPage 
>   ..|--TabbedPage 
>   ....|-- NavigationPage 
>   ......|-- ContentPage

For achieving this, I've used:

- the [Naxam BottomTabedPage](https://github.com/NAXAM/bottomtabbedpage-xamarin-forms), to implement "bottom" TabbedPage on Android (like BottomNavigationView)
- the Syncfusion [SfTabView](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sftabview/overview) control to implement the "top" Tabs
- a **custom renderer** to manage the use of custom icon as "hamburger" icon on the main level, and the "arrow" icon on the childs levels

This renderer looks like this:

```
public class CustomNavigationPageRenderer : MasterDetailPageRenderer
{
    protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);

        for (var i = 0; i < toolbar.ChildCount; i++)
        {
            var imageButton = toolbar.GetChildAt(i) as ImageButton;
            var drawerArrow = imageButton?.Drawable as DrawerArrowDrawable;
            if (drawerArrow == null)
                continue;

            bool displayBack = false;
            var app = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current;
            //var navPage = ((app.MainPage.Navigation.ModalStack[0] as MasterDetailPage).Detail as NavigationPage);
            var detailPage = (app.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).Detail;
            if (detailPage.GetType() == typeof(BottomTp.Views.NaxamMainPage))
            {
                var tabPage = detailPage as BottomTabbedPage;
                var curPage = tabPage.CurrentPage;
                var navPageLevel = curPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count;
                if (navPageLevel > 1)
                    displayBack = true;
            }

            if (!displayBack)
                ChangeIcon(imageButton, Resource.Drawable.icon);
        }
    }

    private void ChangeIcon(ImageButton imageButton, int id)
    {
        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
            imageButton.SetImageDrawable(Context.GetDrawable(id));
        imageButton.SetImageResource(id);
    }
}
```

This works well, but there is **a last problem** when I "return" to the main page:

- there is the default **transition animation from arrow to "hamburger" icon**
- after this, the "hamburger" icon is replaced by my **custom icon**

Here is a short animation to illustrate this issue:

[image]

***Is there a way to deactivate this animation? How could I fix this?***

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27772072/disable-hamburger-to-arrow-animation), `public class MasterDetailPageRenderer : DrawerLayout`, so you can use `DrawerLayout` to achieve your goal.

Comment: Hi @JoeLv-MSFT I've already seen this link, but I don't see how to use DrawerLayout in my renderer.

Comment: Hi, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/listview#creating-the-custom-renderer-on-android), in the `OnElementChanged` method, add the `DrawerClosed`  and `DrawerOpened` event. Can you give me a demo?

Comment: But there is no `OnElementChanged` method in the `MasterDetailPageRenderer`.

Comment: Please check [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/MasterDetailPageRenderer.cs).

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your suggestion...

Comment: There should be the `OnElementChanged` method,  this [link](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/MasterDetailPageRenderer.cs), line 249, you will find `protected virtual void OnElementChanged(VisualElement oldElement, VisualElement newElement)`, but why you said there is no `OnElementChanged` method? I am confused.

Comment: I finally found `OnElementChanged` method: I thought this by mistake because this method isn't purposed defaultly when you type  "`override`".

Comment: So I've added `OnElementChanged` and I've added `DrawerClosed` and `DrawerOpened` like this:
`this.DrawerClosed += delegate (object sender, Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout.DrawerClosedEventArgs e)
            {
                OnDrawerClosed();
            };`

Comment: But it seems that the method `OnElementChanged` is never called when I place breakpoint...

Comment: No, it should be called firstly, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry) is `EntryRenderer`, see this sentence "The EntryRenderer class exposes the OnElementChanged method, which is called when the Xamarin.Forms control is created to render the corresponding native control. "

Comment: Ah sorry, the events are well treated. But only when we open/close the Drawer pane. So this doesn't taken into account the animation that is displayed during the "navigation"...

Comment: Would you like provide a demo?

Comment: The "demo" is still the same: the GIF that is displayed in the main post. You can also get this sample's [sources](https://github.com/Goldstrike/BottomTp).

Comment: You will probably have to deactivate the Syncfusion control that is used in this sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use a custom `NavigationPage`. Here is my [demo](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/BottomTp-MSFT) based on yours.

There are three steps to achieve it:

1) Add a folder named `CustomControl`, create a class `MyNavigationPage` Inherited from `NavigationPage`:

```
namespace BottomTp.CustomControl
{
    public class MyNavigationPage : NavigationPage
    {
        public MyNavigationPage() { }
        public MyNavigationPage(Page root) : base(root) { }
    }
}
```

2) change the tag in your `NaxamMainPage.xaml` file,

Add  `xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:BottomTp.CustomControl;assembly=BottomTp"` in your `naxam:BottomTabbedPage` tag, and then change your `NavigationPage` tag to `controls:MyNavigationPage`:

```
<controls:MyNavigationPage Title="Browse" Icon="md-view-list"
                x:Name="NP1">
    <x:Arguments>
        <views:SfItemsPage   />
    </x:Arguments>
</controls:MyNavigationPage>
<controls:MyNavigationPage Title="About" Icon="md-help"
                x:Name="NP2">
    <x:Arguments>
        <views:AboutPage />
    </x:Arguments>
</controls:MyNavigationPage>
```

3) create custom render `MyCustomNavigationPageRenderer` on Android platform:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyNavigationPage), typeof(MyCustomNavigationPageRenderer))]
namespace BottomTp.Droid.Renderers
{
    class MyCustomNavigationPageRenderer : NavigationPageRenderer
    {
        public MyCustomNavigationPageRenderer(Context c) : base(c)
        { }

        protected override Task<bool> OnPopToRootAsync(Page page, bool animated)
        {
            return base.OnPopToRootAsync(page, false);
        }

        protected override Task<bool> OnPopViewAsync(Page page, bool animated)
        {
            return base.OnPopViewAsync(page, false);
        }

        protected override Task<bool> OnPushAsync(Page view, bool animated)
        {
            return base.OnPushAsync(view, false);
        }

    }
}
```